# Localizing strings in a dynamically created CheckBoxList control

Tags: asp.net, localization, checkboxlist

I have a basic dynamically created Checkbox list in an ascx user control in an asp.net 4 project. Right now it is used to add a list of possible roles (for example, admin, officer, customer) to the checkboxlist control and then the user checks the role they want to apply by looking for those strings.

Code is as follows.

On the page...

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="AvailableToRoles" runat="server" CssClass="Labels" 
    RepeatColumns="3"></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

On the Page_Load it calls a list of string as the data source.

```
this.AvailableToRoles.DataSource = Contact.GetPossibleRoles();
        this.AvailableToRoles.DataBind();
```

Then in an update connected to a button it calls the following string that checks the CheckBoxList roles and add the roles to a contact.

```
List<Role> Roles = new List<Role>();

Roles.Add(Role.GetRole("Admin"));
Roles.Add(Role.GetRole("Officer"));
foreach (ListItem c in this.AvailableToRoles.Items)
{
    if (c.Selected)
    {
        if (c.Text != "Admin")
        {
            Roles.Add(Role.GetRole(c.Text.Trim())); 
        }
    }
}
```

Well now I need to localize this. I have global resource strings that have all the roles listed that can possibly be chosen and I need it to display to the user the global resources in English, Spanish, German and French, and then when it is checked later it searches the values of the roles rather than the resource strings.

Not quite sure on how to do this though without having to radically change the code. Is there an easy way of getting this to work?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add a class that associates a role display name (which is localizable) to a role name (which won't change with localization). Then you can create these and use these in your data binding.

For example:

```
class DisplayableRole
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}
```

Make sure to set the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` properties of AvailableToRoles so that the value is bound to the role name but the display label is bound to the localizable display name. Then just add a method (say WrapInDisplayableRoles) to convert your list of role names to a list of DisplayableRole objects and databind on it:

```
this.AvailableToRoles.DataTextField = "DisplayName";
this.AvailableToRoles.DataValueField = "RoleName";
this.AvailableToRoles.DataSource = WrapInDisplayableRoles(Contact.GetPossibleRoles());
this.AvailableToRoles.DataBind();
```

Then instead of using the `Text` property of your ListItems, use their `Value` property. These will correspond to the RoleName value of your DisplayableRole objects (language-independent).

```
foreach (ListItem c in this.AvailableToRoles.Items)
{
    if (c.Selected)
    {
        if (c.Text != "Admin")
        {
            Roles.Add(Role.GetRole(c.Value)); 
        }
    }
}
```